# A short conjecture on primitive roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I was studying elementary number theory and I made myself the following question: If $m = p.q$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes, which is the maximum value of $k$ such that there is an element over $Z_m$ with order k?
What I did to solve the problem was:

I was trying to make a proof using the following arguments, some of then I can't prove:

First of all, if $r$ is an element $Z_m$ then $|r|$ has to be multiple of $p-1, q-1$.
(I can't prove this)

Second, if $a$ is coprime with $m$ then choosing $n = \operatorname{lcm}(|a|_p,|a|_q)$, where $|a|_q$ is the order of $a$ over $Z_q$ then
$a^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$. 
This has a easy proof.

Third, If $a$ is a solution of $x\equiv r \pmod p$ and $x\equiv 1 \pmod q$ then $|a| = p-1.$

What I did was using the Chinese remainder theorem.

And the last statement:

$\operatorname{max}\{k \in Z : \text{there is} ~c~ \text{with order}~ k\} = \operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1).$

Is quite obvious this statement but I am not so sure if I can prove.

Once all of this is true, can I assure that:

If $m = \prod_{j=1}^rp_j^{\alpha_j}$, then the maximum value of $k$ such that there is $a \in Z_m$ such that $|a| = k$ is given by $\operatorname{lcm}(\phi(p_1^{\alpha_1}),\ldots,\phi_r(p_r^{\alpha_r})).$

Comment: You can! Its bounded by $\phi(m)$.

Comment: The way you phrased the question, you are looking for "the maximum value of $k$ such that there is an element over $\mathbb Z_m$ such that $a^k=1$?".  There is no bound on such $k$.  I expect you meant to ask for the maximum $k$ such that there is an element of order $k$. That has answer $\varphi(m)$.

Comment: I edited @lulu but what you said is not true. Just take such m such that there is no primitive root. Example, $ m = 36$.

Comment: Correct.  I meant "the answer is bounded by $\varphi (m)$".  Gauss showed that the only cyclic cases are $m=2,4,p^k,2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Yes @lulu, I was studying his proof! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, except when $m$ is even, in which case you need to use $\phi(2^e)/2$ in that lcm.

This is the role of the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(n)$.

We always have that $\lambda(n)$ divides $\phi(n)$. Typically $\lambda(n)$ is much smaller than $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Where do I get some proof of his theorem? Could you help me with the intermediate steps that I left? First and last statement?

Comment: @Leonardo, ask a separate question if the explanation in Wikipedia is not enough for you.

Comment: sure, sure, thanks!